# How do I use Django default password reset mechanism into a custom view?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-users

I have some custom registration logic in my project and I want it to work this way:

1. Someone requests access using special page *(Implemented)*
2. New `User` is created. *(Implemented)*
3. Server sends an email using Django's `send_mail` with a single-use link to a password setup page. *(Yet to
   be implemented)*

What's the simplest way to create a single-use link and/or password reset token this using Django's default password reset mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create the desired functionality by implementing very less code.

Follow the below steps:

1. create a token when registering the user using django's `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` class
2. Modify your registration view and set user's `is_active` status to `false` and send user an email with confirm email url containing the token.
3. create view and url to handle user's action when he/she click on email link and set `is_active` status to `true`

You can follow below link for a great tutorial for implementing confirm email functionality in django :
https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef